# SQL Joining - Need single row

Tags: php, sql, join, left-join

My MySQL table structure consists of two tables similar to the following:

```
UserId field1 field2
1       XXX    YYY
2       ABC    DDD
3       EEE    FFF
.
.
.
n       GGG    DDD


UserId  attribute
1        blah
1        adfadf 
1        ddad
2        adff
3        adfa
3        sdff
.
.
.
z        adss
```

Table 1 has only 1 record per ID.  Table 2 has M  records per id.  The ids from table 1 and 2 are related.  My query is similar to the following:

```
SELECT
    t1.`UserId`,
    t1.`field1`,
    t1.`field2`,
    t2.`attribute`
FROM `table1` AS `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `table2` AS `t2` ON `t1`.UserId = `t2`.UserId
WHERE t1.`UserId` = 3
```

The query is returning the following:

```
3 EEE FFF adfa
3 EEE FFF sdff
```

I don't want to return duplicate records for each.  I want to return a single row, something like

```
3 EEE FFF (adfa,sdff)
```

Where the 4th field is a data structure (array? result-set?) that encompasses all the attributes returned for the given userid.

EDIT:::
I see many solutions involving CONCAT, turning this into a CSV.  Would a field having commas potentially mess things up?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?, MySQL?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention.  MySQL

Comment: The only data-structure that can exist in a single field is a primitive data-type.  In this case it would make sense that you end up using a coma delimited string.  You can't put an array in there, you can't nest a data set in there.  Relational databases accomplish what you want with the data in multiple rows, as you already have.  And aggregating multiple values in to a single field is considered a very painful anti-pattern in relational databases.  It makes the data painful to query in so many different ways.  If I may ask, why do you *need* everything aggregating into a single row?

Comment: This is how the database was setup.  I do not want to modify how it was written.  Basically I am querying for a given ID.  I can only expect a variable amount of `attribute`.  If it was up to me I would store attribute as a JSON_ENCODED string in table 1

Comment: @user974896 - I think I may have been unclear.  Separate values on separate rows = `good`.  Combined values into a single field = `bad`.  The current structure is normal best practice in relational databases, I would never recommend the JSON_ENCODED string option.  My recommendation is to not do this at all, unless you have a particular reason that you *need* to do it.  If you do have one I would be interested in knowing it, as we may then be able to comment on whether this approach really is helpful or not.  And *normally* trying to do what you ask is *not* helpful in the long run.

Comment: @user974896 - Values with commas being aggregated into a comma delimited list is just *one* example of why I would say you should *not* do this.

Comment: I see.  I can just run through the result set for each of the X results, aggregating the attributes and taking only the first of the other fields.

Comment: If you post a solution I will give you the credit since you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of my comments:

The only data-structure that can exist in a single field is a primitive data-type.

In this case it would make sense that you end up using a comma delimited string. You can't put an array in there, you can't nest a data set in there. Relational databases accomplish what you want with the data in multiple rows, as you already have. And aggregating multiple values in to a single field is considered a very painful anti-pattern in relational databases. It makes the data painful to query in so many different ways.

In short:

- Separate values on separate rows = `good`.
- Combined values into a single field = `bad`.

The current structure is normal best practice in relational databases, I would never recommend the JSON_ENCODED string option. My recommendation is to not do this at all, unless you have a particular reason that you need to do it. If you do have one I would be interested in knowing it, as we may then be able to comment on whether this approach really is helpful or not. And normally trying to do what you ask is not helpful in the long run.

As per your example, what happens if you have two values which include commas already?  It's just asking for trouble.

If you're really worried about unnecessary network traffic, select from both tables separately and process them in a nested loop.  *(Just make sure that both data-sets are ordered in the same way [by user_id in this case], to make the nested loop as simple as possible.)*

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  As far as the JSON_ENCODING being a good thing, an example comes to my mind.  For a webapp (api) I did some time ago I needed to store the last 10 visitors that viewed the profile.  I would simply pull and JSON_DECODE the object and turn it into a rolling queue.  I would enqueue\deque and UPDATE.  Also works when I want to store an array and preserve the order for one reason or another.  Very easy and I did not have to do any convoluted logic.  I also save several queries.  I knew for a fact I would not have to do reverse lookups on these fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t1.`UserId`,
    t1.`field1`,
    t1.`field2`,
    CONCAT'(',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.`attribute`SEPARATOR ','),')') AS Attributes
FROM `table1` AS `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `table2` AS `t2` ON `t1`.UserId = `t2`.UserId
WHERE t1.`UserId` = 3
GROUP BY  t1.`UserId`,t1.`field1`,t1.`field2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work in your variant of SQL. In T-SQL, this can be accomplished by introducing a local variable. This little sample demonstrates. If you're not familiar, the "WITH" clause is a "common table expression" that easily gives me sample data to work with.

```
declare @temp as varchar(10);
select @temp = '';

with vals as (
    select '1' as a
    union select '2' as a
)
select @temp = @temp +  a + ','
from vals

select '(' + @temp + ')'
```

For your query, simply change that to `select @temp = @temp + attribute`. Of course you'll want to add a little substring code to remove the final extra comma.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP mentioned that this is MySQL while you were writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, one way of doing it would be with [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql, try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). If this fits, please mind that GROUP_CONCAT has a maximum length. You can adjust that with the session variable "group_concat_max_len".

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a join and group by, using the group_concat operator:

```
SELECT t1.`UserId`, t1.`field1`, t1.`field2`,
       concat('(', group_concat(t2.`attribute`, ','), ')')
FROM `table1` `t1` LEFT JOIN
     `table2` AS `t2`
     ON `t1`.UserId = `t2`.UserId
WHERE t1.`UserId` = 3 
group by t1.`UserId`, t1.`field1`, t1.`field2`
```